# How to load data in dhtmlx grid from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dhtmlx

My ajax function is

```
//my grid initialization is here
mygrid.init();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "WeeklyReportConfig.aspx/Showdata",
    data: '{"idno":"' + emid + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
            result = JSON.stringify(result[i]);                
            mygrid.load(result[i], JSON);
        }
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

I am unable to load my dhtmlx grid but I am getting the data from my web method.

Comment: You should be able to access `mygrid` inside your `success` function just fine, are you saying you can't? Can you show the actual code you've tried?

Comment: success: function (result) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                       result = JSON.stringify(result);
                       mygrid.parse(result, "json");
                       mygrid.load(result, JSON);
                   }
               },

Comment: Can you show an example of `result`? And why are you using `stringify`? And why are you looping through `result.d` but not using `result.d[i]` inside the loop?

Comment: @ChrisG i used json.stringyfy to convert this result into json string. and i tries result.d[i] also but it didn't work.

Comment: The point is, why do you need to turn it into JSON? `result` is a JavaScript object, so you should be able to pass it to `mygrid.load()` as-is, I assume. Again: show us an example of `result`, as sent by your web service.

Comment: @ChrisG Result has ReportId ,ReportName ,ReportOwner,.ReportFreq,.ReportDay,ProjectName ,StartDate,EndDate,IsActive

Comment: Add the result in proper JSON to your question.

Answer (score 0):

add **async: false** in ajax method.